# Why does the + function appear to work on tuples?

Tags: syntax, julia

Using the + function on a tuple of two Int64s returns the sum:

```
julia> +((1, 2))
3
```

However, using the + function on a variable that references a tuple gives the following error:

```
julia> a = (1, 2)
(1,2)
julia> +(a)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching +(::Tuple{Int64, Int64})
```

I'm having trouble understanding why it behaves like this, especially when the following code returns true.

```
julia> typeof(a) == typeof((1, 2))
```

Comment: That's very odd! I'm not sure why that happens, but I suspect that it is some strange `promote`ion quirk. To get the sum of a tuple, though, you can use the `sum` function. `sum(a)`

Comment: My guess would be that it is not recognizing `1, 2` as both `Int64`. Not sure if `julia` allows for type casting but if it does try casting your tuple as `(Int64, Int64)`

Comment: Great finding! Which version of Julia are you working over?

Comment: Additionally `*((1,2))` throws an error and `-((1,2))` does not throw an error similarly to `+`.

Comment: I'm using 0.5.0

Answer (score 8):

Note that, contrary to what you might think,

```
julia> :(+((1, 2)))
:(1 + 2)
```

This is a single function call equivalent to `(+)(1, 2)`. There is no tuple, although the syntax may look like there is a tuple. (The `+` function, as you noted, does not work on tuples.) Is this behavior desirable? Well it was reported as a [bug #12755](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/12755), but then fixed. But the fix caused [bug #12771](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/12771) which resulted in the fix being reverted by [pull #12772](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/12772).

The solution to this mess is to avoid calling operators as functions without explicitly writing parentheses. That is, always write `(+)(1, 2)` instead of `+(1, 2)`. You can verify that `(+)((1, 2))` throws the error that you expect.

(This problem only occurs with unary operators, hence why `|` and `*` are not subject to it.)

---

If you're interested, the heart of this problem is a fundamental ambiguity between `+(x, y)` function call syntax and unary operator syntax. Here are a few situations that motivate parsing `+` and `-` as unary operators, even when followed by `(`:

- In `-(x+y)^2`, it is highly likely that `(-)((x+y)^2)` was meant, not `((-)(x+y))^2`. So we cannot simply unconditionally parse `-(` as a function call.
- Instead what must be done is the thing after `-` parsed up to a certain precedence, so that `-x * y` is parsed as `(-x) * y`, `-x + y` as `(-x) + y`, but `-x^y` as `-(x^y)`.
- **Exception:** But this would make `-(1, 2)` parse as `(-)((1, 2))`, that is, a function called on a tuple. For whatever reason or another, it was decided to add an exception for when the thing after `-` looks like a function call tuple. This is so that `+(1, 2)` would work, but this is really mostly just a hack.
- But from the parser's perspective, `((1, 2))` looks exactly like `(1, 2)`; just the former is wrapped in parentheses.

My personal opinion is that the `-(1, 2)` notation is silly (and doesn't work in all cases anyway; e.g. in `-(1, 2)^2`). If that exception weren't around, and `-(1, 2)` consistently parsed as a unary function call on a tuple, then more consistency could be had without (I think) much loss. It's not too bad to just write `1 - 2` or `(-)(1, 2)` when a binary function call is desired.

Comment: That's a great explanation!